# Getting the current year

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Just out of curiosity (as this was the first time I've ever needed to calculate it in Cocoa) -
**Is this *really* the most concise way to calculate the current year?**

```
int thisYear = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] 
                components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]] 
               year];
```

Seems pretty clumsy..

Comment: It's pretty concise as it is, and if it works, why look for even more succinctness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when I need to get components from a date like the day, month or year, I use `NSDateComponents`, fact is dates are clumsy - There are different calendars, time zones, leap years etc.

Comment: Well - after watching the Date/Time related WWDC session with them exotic examples I'm in awe for the poor lads having to implement all that stuff and the whacky edge cases :-)